# Read metadata from PDF to create columns and data in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way SharePoint can create columns and add values to the field from a metadata of a PDF?

The keys could be the column name and values for the data to be filled into the field.